# Greek orthodox prophecy of the messiah in Meteora

Tags: life-of-jesus, eastern-orthodox, greek, messiah

I have attached an image.

This week I traveled to Meteora, Greece to visit the Great Monastery. I found a text there quoting famous Greek persons from ancient times (BC/BCE) writing about a messiah with Christian attributes.

I searched for sources for these quotes but could not find any.
Are these quotes real?
Are there sources?
If these are real, why did the Greek New Testament never quote them?

[image]

Comment: This is fascinating... and very suspect. These seem like clear interpolations.

Comment: I don't suppose you had a photo of this in Greek as well?

Comment: Try asking on quora and share the answers here

Comment: these are definitely fraudulent. Can you post the opposite page or publishing info?

Comment: Given that not every prophecy of the Patristic era is in the NT, and that the NT fulfills 
 OT prophesies from the Hebrew faith tradition, your last element of the question (If They Are Real) is not valid for the context of Christian scripture/prophesy/belief.. THe veracity of the example is certainly of interest.

Answer (score 2):

I've read Aristotle and Plato in Greek and I don't remember those supposed quotations appearing in any of their work -- and I would if they'd been there; such jarringly convenient statements would have jumped out.  So I'm calling those spurious.

The rest are most likely also spurious.  They are all very much like similar statements supposedly found in other sources, which statements have been determined by scholars to be interpolations or, in the case of short statements such as these, sheer inventions.

That you cannot find them strongly suggests that they are spurious; if they were real it would be very easy to find them.